# Selenium TestNG - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to test the login function to Gmail. But it displays an exception error "java.lang.NullPointerException" . Code as follows:

```
    package gmail;

    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.junit.After;
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class Gmail {
        WebDriver driver;

        @Before 
        public void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E://chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        @After
        public void quit() {
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.quit();
        }

        @Test()
        public void login() {

            WebElement txtUserName=driver.findElement(By.name("Email"));
            txtUserName.sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");

            WebElement txtPassword=driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd"));
            txtPassword.sendKeys("abcd123");

            WebElement btnLogin=driver.findElement(By.name ("signIn"));
            btnLogin.submit();
            }
    }
```

**Error:**

```
FAILED: login
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gmail.Gmail.login(Gmail.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:335)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:330)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

===============================================
    Default test

## Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

Comment: there is an non-instantiated variable in class Gmail, on line 33. Here you might have these situations: that variable is somehow instantiated by application context, and TestNG's context is not aware of it, or - the variable is null because of some situation, or you test only part of your code you simply need to mock that variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test annotations does not belongs to TestNG.

Replace

```
@Before with @BeforeTest 
@After with @AfterTest 
@Test should point TestNG library
```

Comment: :) always Welcome; Please keep asking questions!!

Answer (score 1):

In this code snippet @Test annotation belongs to TestNg framework and @Before, @After annotation belongs to Junit framework. Eclipse will show run as TestNG test(since Test annotation is imported from TestNG library) if you run it as TestNG it wont execute @Before and @After(since they belong to Junit framework) therefore **driver** variable is not initialized so we are getting NullPointer Exception

Either we should import Junit Test annotation and run as Junit test or change @After & @Before to @AfterTest & @BeforeTest and run as TestNG test

Answer (score 1):

```
package selenium;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class Aply_login {

WebDriver d;
private By by;
    @Test
    public void aplylogin () throws BiffException, IOException, InterruptedException{

        d.get("http://multishop.orderzen.com/customer/account/login/");
        assertEquals("Customer Login | Multishop",d.getTitle());

File f = new File("F:\\workspace locaiton\\page object model\\aplyinputs.xls");
Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(f);
Sheet s = w.getSheet("Sheet1");


  for(int i=0;i<s.getRows();i++)  {    

          //User name
      d.findElement(By.id("email")).clear();    
      d.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(s.getCell(0,i).getContents());
      String uname =  d.findElement(By.id("email")).getAttribute("value");  

        //Password
      d.findElement(By.id("pass")).clear();
      d.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(s.getCell(1,i).getContents());
      String pass = d.findElement(By.id("pass")).getAttribute("value"); 

        //submit
        d.findElement(By.id("send2")).click();

//Blank user name and blank password (1)
        if (uname.equals("") && pass.equals("")) {
            d.findElement(By.id("advice-required-entry-email"));
            d.findElement(By.id("advice-required-entry-pass"));
            Thread.sleep(6000);enter code here
        }
//Blank user name and valid/invalid  password (2)               
        else if(uname.equals("")){
            d.findElement(By.id("advice-required-entry-email"));
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        }   


//invalid user name blank password  (3)      
    else if(isElementPresent(d,By.xpath(".//*[@id='advice-validate-email-email']"),By.xpath(".//*[@id='advice-required-entry-pass']")))
    {
       d.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='advice-validate-email-email']"));
       d.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='advice-required-entry-pass']"));
       Thread.sleep(6000);
    }
//valid user name & password    (4)
    else if(isElementPresent(d,By.linkText("Log Out"))) {
        d.findElement(By.linkText("Log Out")).click();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
    }
//Invalid user & password  (5)
    else if(isElementPresent(d,By.id("advice-validate-email-email"),By.id("advice-validate-password-pass"))) {
         d.findElement(By.id("advice-validate-email-email"));   
         d.findElement(By.id("advice-validate-password-pass"));
         Thread.sleep(6000);
    }


    else if(isElementPresent(d,By.cssSelector("span..firepath-matching-node"))) {
        d.findElement(By.cssSelector("span..firepath-matching-node"));
    }   
  }



  }

private boolean isElementPresent(WebDriver d2, By linkText) {
    d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    try{
        d.findElement(by);
        return true;
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
         return false;
    }
    }




private boolean isElementPresent(WebDriver d2, By xpath, By xpath2) {
    d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
    try {
        d.findElement(by);
        return true;
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e){    

        return false;
    }

}


@BeforeMethod
    public void setUp()
    {
    // Launch browser
            d=new FirefoxDriver();
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","F:\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
        //d =new ChromeDriver();
    // Maximize window
    d.manage().window().maximize();
    d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown()
    {
    //  Close browser
    d.quit();
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Always check the `import` statements that you are using in your code, make sure it is always the one from desired library. There can be cases where same method exits in multiple classes from different library.

Here you are using `import` statements of `JUnit` instead of `TestNg`.

**Solution:-**

1. Use TestNG import statements.
2. Use `@AfterTest` instead of `@After` annotation.
3. Use `@BeforeTest` instead of `@Before` annotation.

It should help!